# На работает шрифт в IE

Tags: html, css, css3, шрифты

Не работают  шрифты  в IE, шрифты имеются в ttf и eot форматах.
aleo bold  - работает, а остальные нет.  в  других браузерах всё  нормально.
Ладно если  бы  не работали все, а  тут  работет  только  один.
вот как  объвяляю шрифты:

```css
@font-face {
  font-family: "nue-bdcn";
  font-weight: normal;
  font-style: normal;
  src: url("../fonts/HelveticaNeueLTStd-BdCn.eot");
  src: url("../fonts/HelveticaNeueLTStd-BdCn.eot?#iefix") format("embedded-opentype"), url("../fonts/HelveticaNeueLTStd-BdCn.woff") format("woff"), url("../fonts/HelveticaNeueLTStd-BdCn.ttf") format("truetype"); }
```

В чём проблема?

Answer (score 0):

Решение найдено, были использованы шрифты без подписи.